# CHOOSE() not working as intended

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

When I combine random integer generation with `CHOOSE()` I am getting unexpected `NULL` values.

The following should only return letters `a`-`e`, instead `NULL` is also included in the values:

**Query:**

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 RN
              UNION  ALL 
              SELECT RN + 1 
              FROM cte
              WHERE RN < 100)
SELECT DISTINCT CHOOSE(1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5),'a','b','c','d','e','f')
FROM cte
```

**Results:**

```
NULL
a
b
c
d
e
```

**Expected Results:**

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

The random number generation works as expected, returning only values 1-5:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 RN
              UNION  ALL 
              SELECT RN + 1 
              FROM cte
              WHERE RN < 50)
SELECT 1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5)
FROM cte
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/5163/1)

`CHOOSE()` works as follows (index starts at 1):

```
SELECT CHOOSE(3,'dog','cat','horse','fish')  
-- horse
SELECT CHOOSE(8,'dog','cat','horse','fish')  
-- NULL
```

Using random number generation in functions works fine for `LEFT()`,`RIGHT()`,`CHAR()`,etc.
A workaround would be fine, but mostly I'm curious as to why I get `NULL` values at all.

Comment: Interestingly, if you move `DISTINCT 1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5)` to a subquery and use the column from that subquery in `CHOOSE`, you don't get nulls.

Comment: @GSerg I noticed that too, sadly it's not a great workaround for my purposes as I'm using multiple `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` in my `SELECT`, which each generate a random number. Ie:  `SELECT 1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5), 1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5), 1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5)` I could call a number of these in my cte as different columns, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @GoatCO you need to choose between "ideal" and "as intended." This is the way SQL Server works; you need to work around it, whether SQL Server's design is ideal for you or not. As an aside, I marked this as a duplicate, since CHOOSE() expands to a CASE expression, and thus behaves exactly as Paul described in the duplicate. More in my comments below.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed, knowing that it's by design makes working around it obvious regardless of convenience.  Regarding it being marked as a duplicate, while the linked answer certainly helps, it only helps if it's also understood that `CHOOSE()` and `CASE` are handled exactly the same way on the backend.

Comment: @GoatCO Right, that's why I commented as well. I actually only intended to push this to the VtC queue; I totally forgot that gold badge holders were recently granted a binding close vote for duplicates. You could always update the question to show that you see the same behavior when you use the shorthand `CASE` expression.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I wasn't sure if duplicates got deleted or not, hoped given the difference that this one wouldn't be deleted. Probably doesn't matter too much as `CHOOSE()` isn't a function that gets much attention.

Comment: No, they don't, or at least they shouldn't be - duplicates are google juice. [Background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates)

Comment: [Blogged about this here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, probably in the category of a bug.  Of course, what you are doing is strange, because you are treating a random pattern of bits as a number.  Should be valid, but there could be unintended consequences.  And, this is not an overflow problem.  It occurs with other values of `8`.

Witness the following (on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17641)):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 RN
              UNION  ALL 
              SELECT RN + 1 
              FROM cte
              WHERE RN < 100)
SELECT  CHOOSE(1 + ABS(n),'a','b','c','d','e','f'),
        CHOOSE(1 + abs(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5),'a','b','c','d','e','f')
FROM (select abs(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%5) as n
      from cte
     ) n
order by 1
```

The first column is *never* `NULL`.  The second column is periodically `NULL`.  In other words, it makes a difference if you assign the value to another variable.  I could imagine that some pattern of 8-byte big integers represents NaN, but not that this happens so much.

Given that it fails with a direct call but works when there is an intermediate variable, I'm led to the conclusion that this might be some sort of bug.  I wonder if it is documented somewhere.

Comment: Not a bug. CHOOSE expands to a CASE expression, and within the CASE expression, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM is re-evaluated for each potential output. There are obviously times when the first evaluation yields 2, and the next 5 yield 1, pushing you to ELSE territory. [Paul demonstrates this with CHECKSUM(NEWID()) here, but the concept is the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918536/how-does-this-case-expression-reach-the-else-clause/21918828#21918828).

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I would expect the case statement to be `(case arg1 when 1 then val1 when 2 then val2 . . . end)`.  Wouldn't it only evaluate the condition once in that `case`?

Comment: Nope, it evaluates it every time, it is not `case arg1 when 1 then val1 when 2 then val2` it is `case when arg1 = 1 then val1 when arg1 = 2 then val2`.

Comment: And `arg1` is a different evaluation of the function in every case

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . That would explain the observed behavior.  So, `choose()` is in the same category as `coalesce()` as handy functions that SQL Server supports, but you shouldn't use them (in some cases) because the implementation is intentionally broken.  (My editorial viewpoint, of course.)

Comment: I don't think "the implementation is intentionally broken." I think a design decision was made, years ago, and you just don't like the decision. :-) `CHOOSE()` doesn't offer any new functionality, moreover neither does `COALESCE()`. They both just piggyback on existing `CASE` *expression* behavior.

Comment: Microsoft explained why it is as it is in a comment to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions) connect item. "The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of scalar functions."

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . These two functions introduce unnecessary problems.  I guess ANSI doesn't have anything to say about multiple evaluations in `coalesce()`, but it seems odd to have such behavior when `isnull()` works as expected (but just on two arguments).  By the way, I for one have missed you around here.