# SQL's CHOOSE is choosing wrong result (and producing "severe" errors)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
WITH SillySequence (Ordinal) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (1 + Ordinal) FROM SillySequence WHERE Ordinal < 100
)
SELECT
    NeverNull =
        CHOOSE(
            RandomValue,
            'one', 'two'),
    SometimesNull =
        CHOOSE(
            1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2),
            'one', 'two')
FROM (
    SELECT RandomValue = 1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)
    FROM SillySequence
) _
```

Here are few notes:

- `SillySequence` exists solely to produce 100 records.
- `1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)` produces (at random) either 1 or 2.
- `NeverNull` is, well, never `NULL`. The only difference between `NeverNull` and `SometimesNull` is that the first argument for `NeverNull`'s `CHOOSE` function is calculated inside a separate subquery.
- `NULL` values are never produced when using `% 1`. To produce `NULL`, the divisor must be 2 or greater.

The following example chooses between 5, 6, and `NULL` at random. It never chooses any of the other values, which leads me to believe that `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)` is occasionally producing `NULL` when directly provided as an argument to `CHOOSE`.

```
WITH SillySequence (Ordinal) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (1 + Ordinal) FROM SillySequence WHERE Ordinal < 100
)
SELECT
    SometimesNull =
        CHOOSE(
            5 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2),
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
FROM SillySequence
```

Interestingly, I can always trigger a "severe" error with the following:

```
SELECT CHOOSE(
    (SELECT 1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)),
    'one', 'two')
```

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 20
>
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 20
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I've tested the examples above in SQL Server 2016 using compatibility levels `110`, `120`, and `130`.

Comment: NEWID() is evaluated 10 times. CASE and CHOOSE are similar here; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918828/61305).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how `choose()` works.  In my opinion, that is because you are are an intelligent human being who expect software to work in reasonable ways.

The definition of `choose(x, a, b)` is that it is equivalent to:

```
(case when x = 1 then a
      when x = 2 then b
 end)
```

Simply enough when `x` is a constant.  Simple enough when `x` refers to a column (as in your "never null" example).  Simple enough when `x` is a non-volatile expression.  99.9% counter-intuitive (someone might think differently and comment ;) when `x` is a non-deterministic expression.

What does this mean?  Well, you are executing:

```
(case when 1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2) = 1 then a
      when 1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2) = 2 then b
 end)
```

That is, the expression has *two* random numbers.  In fact, one random number for each possible target (I did say "counter-intuitive", didn't I?).

Well, about 25% percent of the time, both comparisons will fail.  And, the result will be `NULL`.  I remember spending many hours debugging code when I first learned this.

Comment: If I remember right, `COALESCE()` suffers similar problems because it gets rewritten to a `CASE` expression.  Particularly confusing because `ISNULL()` *doesn't* work that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The "severe error" remains a mystery, but this explains the original (otherwise inexplicable) behavior.